# jQuery select element with class a, but also it can has class b

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

my first question. Also my english is far form being something I can describe as good, so please be forgiving (don't know better word :)).

I am using php to generate table rows with diffrent style.

```
if ($n % 2 == 0)
    $tr_class = ' class="package_' . $p->package_id . ' alt"';
else {
    $tr_class = ' class="package_' . $p->package_id . '"';
}

<tr<?php echo $tr_class ?>
```

I want to select input field in fifth cell in each row that has class `package_{number here}` and add some styles to it.
To do so, I use that statement:

```
$('tr.package_' + package_errors_ids[i] + ' td:nth-child(5) input[type=text]').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

But second class (`.alt`) does not allow me to do this. 
I don't know how to modify that statement do achieve this.
Will you help? :)

I forgot to write it. It works but not everytime. Package_errors_ids is array containing numbers I use to create unique IDs for distinguish for user invalid packages. When 2 rows are invalid (one has .alt class), both are affected by this code `css('border', '1px solid red');`. But when one is valid, non of these rows are affected.

EDIT:
I've simplified my mixed js and php code in order to generate code without using JavaScript array
http://jsfiddle.net/TAdsT/7/

After this simplification and clearing my webbrowser cache, it works properly! Thank you all for your input. Here's the code (if jsfindle.net erase it):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
<?php
$count = count($this->package_errors_ids);
if ($count > 0)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        echo "$('tr.package_" .
            (int) $this->package_errors_ids[$i] .
            " td:nth-child(5) input[type=\"text\"]').css('border', '1px solid red');\n";
    }
}
?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: it should work, can you prepare a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The class selector already works like that. It selects an element if it has that specific class and it does not matter if said element has other classes as well. There must be something else wrong in your code. Please post an example of the **generated** HTML and if possible a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Instead of editing the title and add `[SOLVED]`, you should **accept** the answer which helped you the most by clicking the tick next to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at this:

```
// in PHP
$('tr.package_' + package_errors_ids[i] + ' td:nth-child(5) input[type=text]')
```

That will generate something like this, I assume:

```
// after PHP
$('tr.package_1 td:nth-child(5) input[type=text]')
```

That won't have any problems at all in selecting a `<tr class="package_1 alt">`. No trouble at all. Assuming your HTML is getting generated correctly, that means you're doing something else wrong. And I'm going to assume that it's this part:

```
input[type=text]
```

Try changing that to

```
input[type="text"]
```

Comment: If i recall correctly, jquery 1.6 above doesnt need quotation marks (on attribute values, that is)

Comment: @Johan ~ That's what I thought, actually. But if there's anything to fault in his code, it's only this I can see. :-/

Comment: Thanks for your input, you simplify my php code. In my time zone it's late, and then it's easy to complicate even simple things :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to use both the classes to access the element

```
$('tr.package_' + package_errors_ids[i] + '.alt td:nth-child(5) input[type=text]')                   
   .css('border', '1px solid red');
```